# Select JSON objects based on unique ID in Google Cloud Bigtable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I recently started working on Google Cloud Platform. Let's say, I have a Bigtable named `sample_table` which consists of JSON objects. If I need first 500 objects I have something as:

```py
for key, data in sample_table.scan(limit=500):
```

How I can select objects based on keys(unique ID) using Python? for example: in range between `bm_450:bm_500` i.e objects between `450 to 500`.

Comment: I am not familiar with this, but upon reading I found that you can "Read a row by its key" using `Table.read_row()`. Perhaps with a simple while loop?

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ How to select json object based on range? If want to iterate only objects in between range of key `bm_450 to bm_500`?

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest native Python client (`google-cloud-bigtable == 0.29.0`), you can scan rows by using `read_rows` method on your table instance, with `start_key` and `end_key` parameters :

```py
some_rows = sample_table.read_rows(start_key="bm_450", end_key="bm_500")
```

Note that here, you'll be retrieving all lines between `bm_450` (included) and `bm_500` (excluded).

Then you can iterate rows with something like this :

```py
some_rows.consume_all() 

for row_key, row in some_rows.rows.items():
    key = row_key.decode('utf-8')
    cell = row.cells[column_family][qualifier][0]
    value = cell.value.decode('utf-8')
    print('\t{}: {}'.format(key, value))
```

The last example is inspired by [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-python-hello). You can find samples [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigtable/hello/main.py).